# User settings in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-design

I am trying to design an efficient database schema for user settings in SQL Server 2008 R2.  The wrinkle here is that we need multiple levels of granularity, and I'm not sure how to efficiently represent that.

We have a handful of settings that can be applied to a full *Account*, a single *Module*, or a specific *Feature*.  Currently the way the table has been set up is something to the effect of:

```
AccountId int
ModuleId int
FeatureId int
SettingData string
```

(please don't get hung up on what SettingData is or isn't, I just made it a string here in the example to distinguish it from the other Ids).

**Problem:** Many customers have access to many modules, and these modules have access to many features.  A single Account making a change to SettingData can modify 4000 records.  This is absolutely not tenable for obvious reasons, and I'm determined to fix it.

The solution is obviously to have a few different tables that, by their usage, override eachother and allow some account wide settings and granular preferences.  However, I've never done this before and my attempts at designing it end up looking disturbingly similar to the inefficient table structure we currently have.

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Other than different locking depending on the scope of a single user's setting change, what do you expect to gain from multiple tables?

Comment: Hopefully modifying a lot fewer records when a user changes a setting.

Comment: But what does that gain you? If a user is locking their set of rows, they should be on the same set of pages, so shouldn't escalate beyond a range... unless you plan to have multiple users modifying the same account at the same time, in which case separate tables won't help you? Are you prematurely optimizing for a performance problem you don't have yet?

Comment: @YYY: It appears from the question that there is a many-to-many relationship between Accounts and Modules, but the relationship between Modules and Features is not apparent - "these modules have access to many features" - is this a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship?

Comment: @Aaron Yeah, this definitely isn't a performance problem we don't have.

Comment: @Mark: I am inclined to say many-to-many because you're correct in that each module has access to a number of features, but these features are meaningless unless they're expressed in the context of an Account.  So, from a logical standpoint, yes, they're many to many.  But realistically, they'd never be expressed unless associated with an Account, so they end up being one to many to many, if that makes sense.  That is the general situation I've never messed with, and the part that's got me confused.

Comment: @Aaron - Frankly, I'd be more worried about referential integrity with that design, then any possible performance gains.  I think I want more information about what possible settings there are - as much as they bug me, this may be one of the times to use an EAV.  There should probably be tables between each level and setting, then referenced as `SELECT COALESCE(<feature_setting>, <module_setting>, <account_setting>)`.

Comment: @X-Zero Nothing wrong with EAV, it all depends on the control you have over your data. I've blogged about this. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway.aspx

Comment: @X-Zero: All of our settings at this point are booleans, and there's a handful of them.  I'm not opposed to using something like an EAV, the larger thing I'm concerned about is how to relate all these things together without falling back into the original trap, which effectively has 3 different primary keys and is causing the table to grow at a nearly cubic rate.

Comment: @YYY: So to clarify: a specific feature is never associated with more than one account?

Comment: @YYY: I'm still fuzzy on the actual relationships here.  Many accounts, many modules, many features.  Each account can change many modules.  Each module can change many features.  But features don't change modules, and modules don't change accounts, correct?  That sounds like one to many, one to many.  What I feel is missing is detail on how many settings an account can change in one transaction?  Are SettingData changes collated into a batch, and then the batch is executed?  Or are we really looking at an account being able to change thousands of settings, but one at a time?

Comment: @Mark: In essence, yes.  A feature is something like a text message alert when a specific thing happens, right?  Well, we can do that for multiple accounts, it's just that it's completely meaningless if it's not associated with an account.  But a 'specific feature', that is, a specific instance of a feature, would never be associated with more than one account.

Comment: @pheedbaq: They are being batched in the sense that if someone makes an Account-wide change right now it will change it for all modules, all features, which boils down to something like `Update dbo.settings set SettingData = @settingData where AccountId = @accountId`.  However that level of change currently requires 4000 rows to change and that is only going to go up and up as time goes on and more modules and features are added.  Things are already starting to drag a little bit on our website, so as this goes up to 10k or 15k it might even start causing timeouts. Does that help?

Comment: @YYY: Based on your comment to Mark, it sounds like you have a sort of inheritance of the settings.  Settings at the account level are inherited to the module level unless explicitly set at the module level.  Settings at the module level are inherited to the feature level unless explicitly set at the feature level.  So that's why you could have 4K changes all at once.  I get that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though settings can currently be specified at the following levels:

- Account
- Module
- Feature

Given that there are probably already tables set up for each of Account, Module and Feature, it would appear to make sense to:

- Remove the existing table.
- Set up a new field for setting data on each of the existing Account, Module and Feature tables.

Since the general principle is that the specific should override the general, a Module-level setting should override an Account-level setting, and a Feature-level setting should override a Module-level setting.

The advantage of this approach is that any time a specific setting was updated, only a single record would need to be updated.

The disadvantage is that to determine which setting should apply to a specific feature (for a specific account) in a specific module, 3 tables would have to be queried instead of one.

Comment: To clarify: Accounts are the most general form of setting, so module-level should override account-level, which should then be overridden by feature - this is because modules and features are never expressed without relationship to an account.  The idea is the same, though, so thanks a lot for this, I'll start playing with it to see if I can make it go.  Also, thanks for the reminder regarding SettingData, but that's fortunately not a problem in this situation.  In the real instance of the problem there are multiple setting fields that I just crunched together to simplify the question.

Comment: @YYY: That makes things a lot simpler - I have updated my answer accordingly.